# Translation plugin with Loco Translate

Tags: wordpress

I use the author's foreign [plugin link to the plugin files](https://github.com/Automattic/o2/), which displays [theme text](https://github.com/paulgibbs/p2-breathe), text and comments functionality on top of the texts.
I create a translation in the usual way through the Loco Translate plugin for the WordPress site. Fortunately it is similar to the Poedit program and works no worse.
As usual, two MO and PO files were created on the basis of a pot file.
the translation is ready.
Loco Translate shows all the green check marks. the names of the files with the original match. everything is good.
The problem is that the texts on the site remained in English.
Rechecked through other browsers, cleared the cache and updated the page.
It did not seem. There are no translations of the text.
What could be overlooked that the translation remained hidden? and it's missed that, there is no load_theme_textdomain in the plugin. meaning that the topic should pull it up. but the problem remained unresolved.
*Sorry if the message is spelled with errors.*

Answer (score 1):

Translations only appear once a plugin or theme is at least 95% translated into that locale.

https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/frequently-asked-questions/#strings-are-validated-when-are-they-taken-into-account-for-download

Comment: It would be nice if there were a way of changing that threshold to get a translation from a .po file with a lower percent...